# Charge a test account on testRPC

Tags: ether, testrpc, erc-20

I am running [this sample code](https://0xproject.com/wiki#Intro-Tutorial:-Create,-Validate,-Fill-Order) but I got an error because my fake account has 0ETH, how I can charge my account ?

```
try {

        // Unlimited allowances to 0x proxy contract for maker and taker
        const setMakerAllowTxHash = await zeroEx.token.setUnlimitedProxyAllowanceAsync(ZRX_ADDRESS,  makerAddress);
        await zeroEx.awaitTransactionMinedAsync(setMakerAllowTxHash);
        console.log('Maker allowance mined...');

    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

> Error: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost
>   is: 47275 and the senders account only has: 0